# Binding a property to a style/resourcedictionary of a view

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

One of my views consists of 5 `UserControls` that each display data about a certain object. Let's say for example that the view displays the cows our company has, and on the screen cows 1 through 5 are displayed (each in their own UserControl).

What I want to do (but not sure is possible) is to bind the status of a cow to the style used in its respective UserControl. So we have a property `status` that could be `ok`, `hungry`, `dead` for example. In case the cow is `ok` I want to display a 'normal' style, if it's `hungry` I want the background to be red and if it's `dead` I want the text to be black and the fontsize increased.

I've added a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve. My knowledge of WPF styles/resource dictionaries is still somewhat limited though.

**What I basically want in code**
A ViewModel with a `Status` property

```
class CowInfoViewModel : Screen
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; } //"ok", "hungry", "dead"
}
```

A View that retrieves a style or resourcedictionary

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfModifyDifferentView.Views.CowInfoView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <!-- A reference to a ResourceDictionary with styles, that is bound to the 'Status' property -->

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Name" Text="Cow Name"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Status" Text="Ok" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**EDIT - Solution:**

I did the following using Vale's answer:

In the xaml (reference to the converter):

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Converters:CowStyleConverter x:Key="styleConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

In the xaml (elements):

```
        <TextBlock x:Name="Name" Text="Cow Name" Style="{Binding Path=Style, ConverterParameter='TextBlockCowName', Converter={StaticResource styleConverter}}" />
```

The converter (note I left out the checks):

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var status = value.ToString();
        var styleName = parameter.ToString();

        _resourceDictionary.Source = new System.Uri(string.Format("pack://application:,,,/Resources/ScreenI2Style{0}.xaml", status));

        return _resourceDictionary[styleName];
    }
```

Then I created multiple ResourceDictionaries with styles such as:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBlockCowName" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource SomeBrush}" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind UserControl Style property to Status and use a converter.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfModifyDifferentView.Views.CowInfoView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfModifyDifferentView"
             Style="{Binding Path=Status, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}">
        <UserControl.Resources>
            <local:MyConverter x:Key="myConverter" />
        </UserControl.Resources>
```

I assume that your converter is in WpfModifyDifferentView directly.
Converter will look like this:

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter {
        private ResourceDictionary dictionary;

        public MyConverter() {
            if (dictionary == null) {
                dictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
                dictionary.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfModifyDifferentView;Component/Resources/Styles.xaml");
            }
        }
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
            switch (value.ToString()) {
                case "ok":
                    return dictionary["myKeyForOkStyle"] as Style;
                case "hungry":
                    return dictionary["myKeyForHungryStyle"] as Style;
                case "dead":
                    return dictionary["myKeyForDeadStyle"] as Style;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

You need to specify the correct URI of course.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) at the moment some other issues turned up at the place I work. I'll be trying this asap

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, I just tried it and it works nicely :) I was just wondering if it is possible to change the styles of multiple elements? (A style always has a `TargetType` for some specific element right?) For example, I would like to upgrade the UserControl, a Grid, Borders and TextBlocks, but (afaik) a different style element is required for each of these. Does this mean I will have to have an additional switch statement within the `Status` cases to get an elements respective style?

Comment: Yes, a different style is required if you are doing something specific for that type. But if you want to change general (base) properties you can set TargetType to Control or FrameworkElement for example. And yes, if you want to use the same conveter on different types with different styles, you can check targetType parameter in adition to switch statement.

Comment: Got it to work by setting both the `Path` (status) and `ConverterParameter` (style name) in the xaml. I'll update my question a bit to show the outcome, thanks again!